# Run code on every frame two colliders are in contact

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, if-statement, while-loop

im trying to make it so that if my character continues to touch a gameobject with a damage script the player continuesly gets damaged. instead of this result i only get damaged once when touching the gameobject. there are no error messages. ive tried to replace the if with a while loop and it ended up crashing my game.  is there any way to loop a if statement preferably with a way to time it.

```
if (other.tag == "Player")
{
   healthScript.healthPoints -= damage;

}
```

this is the if statement im trying to loop.

Comment: You wouldnt do it that way but yes you set it up as a trigger and while the trigger is still true you do it, while its not triggered you dont

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the code that triggers the touch event i.e. that causes this if statement to be executed in the first place. I imagine somewhere there is a code like "while (stillTouchingThing) ... If (other.tag == "Player") ..."  if that is the case to avoid crashing your program you'll need to break out of the loop if some condition is met e.g. healthScript.healthPoints < 0.

Comment: `OnTriggerStay`

Comment: The engine controls the loop, not you. @Draco18snolongertrustsSE's response is correct.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am under the assumption you are using Colliders as triggers with the `Is Trigger` attribute selected. I am also assuming this is a 2D game. If not, this same approach will work, you will just have to change the methods from 2D to 3D.

You will want to add the  `OnTriggerEnter2D()` and `OnTriggerExit2D()` methods to your player health script. These will allow us to detect when the player is standing on the damaging object. From here, we will start a coroutine which can be used to deal damage in a timed manner.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class HealthScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float healthPoints = 100f;
    public float damage = 5f;
    public bool OnDamagingObject = false;

    IEnumerator DealDamage()
    {
        while (OnDamagingObject)
        {
            healthPoints -= damage;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D hitInfo)
    {
        GameObject collider = hitInfo.gameObject;
        if (collider.tag == "DamagingObject")
        {
            OnDamagingObject = true;
            StartCoroutine(DealDamage());
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D hitInfo)
    {
        GameObject collider = hitInfo.gameObject;
        if (collider.tag == "DamagingObject")
        {
            OnDamagingObject = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your routine is frame-rate dependent. You need to scale the damage with something like `healthPoints -= damage * Time.deltaTime;` otherwise the damage will be faster in high end systems and slower on low end systems.

Comment: Again, `OnTriggerStay` exists.

Comment: 'OnTriggerStay' would make the code easier to read, but much slower. Not something you'd notice on a single instance, but If you start checking on many instances it may become a problem. Additionally, 'OnTriggerStay' is not called on the first FixedFrame, but only on the second.

Comment: I'd argue OnTriggerStay() does not make the code more readable as all logic pertaining to dealing the damage would have to be contained solely within that method. Implementing both OnTriggerEnter() and OnTriggerExit() is a more robust solution which allows the developer to better control how and what happens when the player interacts with the damaging object.

Comment: In fact, OP mentioned they wanted to deal damage in a timed manner. I have updated my answer to include a coroutine which subtracts from the health and then uses WaitForSeconds() before subtracting again. This would not be as simple with OnTriggerStay().

Comment: If you're going to start and end a coroutine, `StartCoroutine` returns a `Coroutine` object that you can pass to `StopCoroutine`.

Comment: @kefren Not really. There is some overhead in the Unity magic methods, but if a trigger isn't being collided with, then it doesn't call `OnTriggerStay`. As a result it doesn't make much difference if you have one or thousands, the performance difference is negligible. You'd be correct if there were thousands with an `Update` method (or if the player was somehow inside all of the colliders), though.

Comment: Unity messages come with a rather big overhead, so if many colliders overlap, the impact becomes significant. Moreover, checking the tag with `other.tag=="somestring"` creates a lot of garbage. Using `CompareTag()` would be better, but still rather slow.

Comment: @kefren CompareTag is faster ofc, but it is such a small micro optimization that i would avoid suggesting to newcommers, same applies to OnTriggerStay overhead

Comment: @Menyus nonetheless, OnTriggerStay is suggested instead of the above answer, and I still think that it’s in no way better than the answer we are commenting. About CompareTag, the very fact that one is a beginner justifies learning the best, since it takes the same time learning one or the other. Changing habits later, is much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

For those who wish to use `OnTriggerStay()`, I will also provide a solution for that. This time, we will keep the script on the damaging object, following the structure the question asker is using.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DamageScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public HealthScript healthScript;
    public float damage = 5f;

    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D hitInfo)
    {
        GameObject other = hitInfo.gameObject;
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            healthScript.healthPoints -= damage;
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments of my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59596559/12041806), implementing both `OnTriggerEnter()` and `OnTriggerExit()` allow more control over dealing damage to the player. One of the downsides to using `OnTriggerStay()` is I am unsure how to deal the damage in a timed manner. Additionally, `OnTriggerStay()` limits how you can deal damage to the player. If in the future you wanted to give 5 damage to the player when they first touch the damaging object but 2 damage for every second thereafter while touching it, it is not possible to do so using `OnTriggerStay()`.